# mystery thread "net_rim_cldc-2" causing slow performance

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry, java-me, profiler

I have ran the profiler.

And I am getting some thread running 85%!

A thread I have no idea about. And have not called?

It worked fine on the emulator. But now is experiencing lag beyond acceptable on a real phone.
I only just got it today, so it's fresh with no other 3rd party apps on it.

Below is the eclipse profiler info trimmed to the important parts.
What is this thread called `net_rim_cldc-2`? What on earth is it doing?
When is it called? What am I doing to call it?

```
PROFILER
net_rim_cldc-2  --------------------------- 85%
-- Class.forName0 ( String ) ----------- 84%
-- Class.forName ( String )-------------- 84%
helloworld ----------------------------------- 10%
```

I'm running on BB 9860. SDK 7.0. And built using Eclipse.

Comment: Are you doing any lengthy operations on the event thread? Please can you post some code?

Comment: Although its called helloworld, in reality its my app, and theres a lot of code being run yes. Drawing to screen. But at no point do I call new threads. So I dont know what this new thread is doing.

Comment: According the name it is from the hostsystem. Or at least from the framework you used to build the application ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

net_rim_cldc are OS modules (as described [here](http://yohan.es/blackberry/net_rim_cldc/))
this must be an OS thread